# How to speed up Flat File Database in PHP?

Tags: php

I noticed that ffdb in PHP are awfully slow. So how would  I go about speeding up the ffdb without SQL?

Comment: be more detailed please. you cannot compare variant A without any B and comparison criteria + conditions.

Comment: Is there some reason you think you should be able to speed it up?  Are you making complicated queries that you think you should optimize?  Can you show some examples?

Comment: if you really need to go for such things as speed, reliability, etc, go for a dedicated database like mysql

Comment: Agreed, too little information. Please help define 'slow' by indicating what you are getting vs what you expect. Some hints on what you're using would also help, as well as the size of the ffdb and complexity of your i/o requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flat file will become more slow the more data it's contain. This is because in order to get a data, the engine need to get all data first into memory, then select the requested data.

SQL database have random seek feature, because the data placement is in a known location, plus it have index table. That's why any SQL database is not affected with the number of data stored in it.

You can try [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) if you need single file database. Firefox and Thunderbird use sqlite to store bookmark and browsing history.

Answer (score 0):

Tokyo Cabinet is amazingly fast for key/value lookups. There is also the search addition (tyrant) that allows for more complex queries

http://1978th.net/tokyocabinet/
PHP implementation
http://code.google.com/p/phptyrant/